# Table of contents web part remove max 50 limit - without editing the web.config file

Tags: web-config, web-part

I know that to remove the max 50 limit on a TOC web part you can edit the web.config file by adding `DynamicChildLimit="0"`, but I unfortunately do not have access to the server itself to be able to do this.

Just wondering if anyone has a different solution which would give the same result? Or amend the TOC web part/xsl sheets to show the next 50 sites - ie. 51 to 100?

I've looked everywhere for an alternative solution to this, but can't find any. Perhaps this is an indicator that it can't be acheived.

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: I have the same problem but unfortunately I do not have SP 2010. I am running on 2007 version. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If this is for SharePoint 2010, you should be able to set this value through SharePoint.

1. Go to the site collection you are wanting to change this on.
2. Click Site Actions > Site Settings > Navigation.
3. There are options there for 'Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation:'  which is defaulted to 20.  Change that to what ever number you want and it should be all better.

Note that there are two places you can change, one for Global Navigation and one for Current Navigation.

Comment: thx for your reply. How can i get this done? Is it possible to implement it within a web-part page by coding? oder by using the sharepoint designer somehow?
Unfortunately I have not created any new web-part yet - would be the first time, so a would appreciate detailed help:) THANKS in advance!

Comment: The navigation provided for SP 2010 worked great for us to resolve this problem - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is actually the simplest way. You could effectively inherit from the TOC and override DynamicChildLimit.